# Keep get parameters when submitting a form

Tags: jsf-2, java-ee-6

I'm trying to do something simple in JSF but I can't get it working for some reason.
What I want is to post information with a form from a page reached with a GET parameter and keep this GET parameter whenever I submit the form.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="someId" value="#{someController.something}" converter="#{someConverter}" />
</f:metadata>
```

This is the way I choose to bind the GET parameter, this is working fine when I'm doing the GET request.

On the very same page I have a

```
<h:form>
    <!-- (... various input ...) -->
    <h:commandLink action="#{someController.create}"  value="Create" />
</h:form>
```

When I submit it, even if data are right, I never get my "something" not to be null.

The use case is easy, I have a one to many relation and I want to access the "one" with the id as a GET parameter and list the "many" on the page and below the listing the form allows me to add a new element in the "many" list.

I'd like to make it work (of course) and be the cleaner possible,

Could someone tell me what's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the `SomeController` bean `@ViewScoped` so that the bean lives as long as you're interacting with the same view,

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SomeController {
    // ...
}
```

or use `<f:param>` in `UICommand` components to pass GET parameters through

```
<h:commandLink>
    <f:param name="someId" value="#{param.someId}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using CDI instead of JSF for the container because I heard JSF container was deprecated. Shall I keep my choice or use ManagedBean instead? If I stick with CDI what's best approach, using @SessionScoped? Thank you

Comment: Deprecated? :) Nonsense. They're still applicable on barebones servletcontainers which doesn't support CDI out the box like Tomcat/Jetty/etc. Only whenever you've a container which supports CDI and you'd like to inject managed beans in other Java EE artifacts like servlets, filters, webservices, EJBs, etc, then CDI is indeed easier to use. The session scope is absolutely the wrong choice. CDI offers `@ConversationScoped` as substitute for the view scope, but you'd need to begin and end the conversation yourself.

Comment: Is it a good practice in an application to use both ManagedBean & CDI or shall I use only one? Thank you for your answer, that was clear and concise, problem solved!